# swift UITableView lags with images

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, swift, lag

I would like to show images in TableView so I created a custom cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

    if let image =  UIImage(data: self.photos[indexPath.row].image) {

        if image.size.width > image.size.height {

            tableView.rowHeight = view.bounds.width *  0.71

        } else { tableView.rowHeight = view.bounds.width *  1.22

        }

        cell.cellImage.image = image
    }
```

I had a problem how to adjust cell's height so for each image its calculated separately and I use clip subviews for ImageView.

The problem is that when I start adding photos the scroll of table is very laggy :(
Even when I remove cell's height calculation nothing's changed.

Does Anyone has any idea how to make it smooth in Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should never change row heights in the middle of creating table cells. Row height changes are very expensive for `UITableView`. You should use the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView(heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` to tell the table view what each cell height should be. This is almost certainly your major problem.

A lesser problem is that creating a `UIImage` from data is somewhat expensive, and you keep creating new images and and then throwing them away.

The solution to both of these is simple. Create all your images once and put them in your model. Then `tableView(cellForWRowAtIndexPath:)` can just assign the already-created image to the imageview, and `tableView(heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` is trivial to implement.

(I'm assuming here that you actually want each cell to have a different height. It's a little confusing from your question whether that's the case. If you want them all to be the same, just set `rowHeight` once when your data comes in.)

Comment: main problem was with UIImage - when I create them once at the beginning the load much faster. But I still have lags when  scrolling down - I moved creating cell to heightForRowAtIndexPath:                  let image =  self.photosTemp[indexPath.row].image
        
        if image.size.width > image.size.height {
            
            return view.bounds.width *  0.71
            
        } else { return view.bounds.width *  1.22
            
        }

Comment: `creating a UIImage from data is somewhat expensive` this saved me!